# Python - split a string with regular expression results and strip it

Tags: python, string, select, split, strip

I need to write a function that will take a string as an argument and gives the description of the string as output. So when i insert the following string in my function:

```
"12:30 – 13:00        Red Light Radio – Ovational Exercises"
```

The output should be:

```
"Red Light Radio – Ovational Exercises"
```

I know i can get rid of all the spaces by using .strip() but i can't figure out how to split the sentence between the date and the description. I use regular expressions to find the time so i can split the sentence at the last index of the time but it is not fully working

My current code:

```
def extract_activity(string):
    time_expressions=re.findall(r'[\d.:]+.*[\d.:]+', string)[0]
    string.split(time_expressions[-1])

    return string


test = "12:30 – 13:00        Red Light Radio – Ovational Exercises"
extract_activity(test)
```

I want "Red Light Radio – Ovational Exercises" as result but my split command is not working.
The split command should split the string up into 2 strings one containing the time and the other one containing the letters, after that i should use .strip() to get rid of all the spaces.

All help will be appreciated

Comment: What is the output of `extract_activity(test)`? Does it cause an error?

Answer (score 0):

Just match the whole line:

```
mtch = re.match('^\s*\d+:\d+\s*-\s*\d+:\d+\s+(.*?)\s*$', text)
activity = mtch.group(1)
```